# Erro para gerar o APK no IONIC 3

Tags: ionic3

O problema só ocorre ao da o comando:

```
$ Ionic cordova build android
```

> cordova build android.
>
> Android Studio project detected
>
> [10:58:09]  lint finished in 4.20 s
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\diario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_161
>   studio
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)>
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.>
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Unable to start the daemon process.
>     This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>     For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>     Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
>     4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
>   ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Answer (score 1):

João,
Seu problema parece estar relacionado a essa explicação aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp/497757#497757
A JVM não está conseguindo alocar 2gb (2097152KB object heap) de memória contígua, verifica se o seu computador tem essa memória disponível.
Uma dica que a pessoa do link dá é migrar para o windows 64bits, pois ele trabalha com uma memória virtual com muito mais espaço, e então a JVM conseguirá alocar essa memória.

Comment: Realmente, o meu computador esta com windows 64x porém o Java esta com 86x, talvez seja isto  que esta causando este problema. Obrigado!